# If everything travels through spacetime at c, then what about gravitational time dilation?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, speed-of-light

[image]

"An object's motion through space-time is always equal c. If motion through time is increased then the motion through space will b decreased and vice versa."

Based on this assumption, how can we explain time dilation caused by gravity. Because If I stand still on a gravitational field, magnitude of x, the time dilation will be y, but if I stand still on a gravitational field, magnitude of 2x, the time dilation will be greater than y.

But in all case, even my motion through space isn't changed, motion through time is changed under gravity.

So it seems that: the assumption of "everything has speed of c" isn't valid under gravity. Is that right? Or can we make an explanation for that based on that diagram?

Comment: Where did you get this notion that an object always moves a speed c? It seems wrong.

Comment: @mmeent, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity#Magnitude

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Four-velocity in General-relativistic geodesic equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273533/)

Answer (score 0):

The first argument, using the asymmetry of throwing a magnet on a conductor, and throwing a conductor on a magnet is that in one case there is an induced electric field and in the other there is none. So using only a magnetic field, one would measure an E field and one would measure none. but simple Galilean relativity forbids this. Conclusion is that there is no absolute rest frame.

Using Maxwell we get that the speed of light is absolute. Thus light can find no rest.

If you have mass (disregarding gravity for a sec) just luck at your clock and measure the magnitude of your linear element. ct. thus you go in spacetime as c. since the linear element is invariant, your go as c in all other inertial frames.

In Einstein's restricted theory of relativity, the only explicit law are the laws of the classical electromagnetism, plus the good old principals of relativity.

The formal postulate is the physical constant c. The dimensions are length=time and all else can be derived.

Thus, SO(3,1). Lorentz is in charge of geometry, of vectors of tensors and of scalars.

Moving to Gravity/Relativity/Geometry, non restricted:

1. Lorentz co variance is promoted to general co variance. In the first paper,Einstein proposes a physical/dynamical/logical system and blames Isaac Newton for having no complete epistemological explanation for it. (Newton did not publish any response).
2. No prior geometry: space time is pseudo Riemann manifold naturally. Any solution found is not really necessarily a physical solution. And, Whatever solution you choose may or may not be used against you if you impose some "more general co variance" on it.
3. Sanity is restored in infinitesimal regions of space time and you may Lorentz your way to find where is space and where is time. The Lorentz representations are restricted to the algebra near you, if gravity is switched on. For finite objects, you need the connection of the metric to calculate things far from you, and walking is replaced by doing an integral.

If you observe a guy+slow clock and at rest it is as if he is going in space time with some v smaller than c. Think of an ordinary geographical map as an analogy. You got all the coordiantes right and put your finger on the spot, But the table the map is on is flat and the geography is intrinsically curved. Ironing it on a flat table tears and distorts it.

Where the guy is at it looks as if everything is moving away from you and at rest. Why? because time has some divergence in to space. the time basis vector is finite rotated a bit, just like in the case where there is actually a relative velocity. But in the general/gravitation the diverging is not local and infinitesimal.

So he is going in c, but you gotta use the right map to see it. not distort it to your locally flat space.

Now for the case of "standing still in a gravitational field": if i give u a floating compartment at rest in your eyes and ask you to relax inside it, you would be pressed against the wall. in relativity rest is when you feel weightless. which you do not. You could argue that the compartment is actually accelerating and there is no gravitational field. because locally the spacetime is flat in any case.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how this response answers the question of the magnitude of four-velocity in a gravitational field.

Comment: so go  linear and quantize it twice.

Comment: What I'm referring to is differential geometry. Einstein gravity field as read from the left hand side of the field equation is purely geometry. When you look at him before having a chance to think it is perceived as if he is on your tangent linear vector spacetime.  This is principally false. Send him some light of a certain energy/frequency. Can you tell what is the energy he will measure just by measuring that his wrist watch ticks slower than yours?  can you tell what is the energy you will measure if he gives you back your light? what about light from his flashlight?